# http access to subdomain only if logged in on www

Tags: apache-2.2, php, http

Is it possible to allow http access to a subdomain ONLY IF a user is logged in on the main domain (www)?

Comment: Using what method is the user logged in on the main domain? Open for alternatives in that regard? Should/must the access to the subdomain be controlled at the HTTP level?

Comment: what do you mean by "is logged in on the main domain"? www in itself is a subdomain so your question is quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You could check login at application level by session and cookies, try with a cookie valid for entire domain.

Maybe this is question for [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).